# Xcode #import not finding .h file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import

I'm trying to import a .h file from an old xcode project into my current one. The file location is the same as the other files in the project (I moved it there), but after using #import in my program body file, when I try to run the program I get the following fail:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Fraction", referenced from:

objc-class-ref-to-Fraction in 9.1main.o

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you also added Fraction.m to the project,

In the Group & Files view, select **Fraction.m**

Show the Editor view (Menu-->View-->Zoom Editor Out)

Select the Detail tab. There you should (again) see the Fraction.m file.

At the far right of the column there is a tiny target symbol. Make sure that column has a checkmark.

That ensures that your class **Fraction** is included when Xcode builds the app.

Comment: Of course! Actually I forgot the .m file entirely; I had been at it way too long... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It happened the same to me, what I did was this:

1.- Click @ the "Show the project navigator" tab.

2.- Select your program's folder, the same that contains your main file, ie. "Program 1"

3.- In that same tab, go to the left bottom of the screen,  there are 4 signs and a search window. Click on the icon on the left, the one with a "+" sign (add a new file).

4.- From the rollup window, select: "Add files to program..." .

5.- A new finder window appears, look for the files you want to add, (.h and .m for example) Click the "Add button"...

Voila!

Note that the files you are adding MUST be in the same folder as your main file, otherwise you'll have problems when compiling.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode Project Settings -> Build Phases -> In Headers Section look for your .h file and move it to Public list.